# Multiple data elements in single Parse Push RETS API request

Tags: parse-platform

I was wondering if here is a way to send multiple 'data' elements in a single Parse REST API push request. I know we can send the same message to multiple devices or channels as required. But i have a different message for each channel. So what i need is a way to call Parse REST API once with the JSON of different channels but each with a different data and alert message.

is is possible? or do i need to make such requests one by one.

Comment: multiple requests are necessary.

Comment: okie ...got it. But having some dynamic way to set part of the message as a wildcard to be replaced later would have been lovely.

Comment: Hopefully we'll add templates/localization at some point..